# CKeditor doesn't format the body value

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am building a website in Hindi language. I was given a Database containing rows of title and body. I created a node for each row using this code :

```
$query = db_select('hindi', 'n')
      ->fields('n', array('title','body'))
      ->execute();

foreach($query as $item) {
    $title = $item->title;
    $body = $item->body_value;
    $values = array(
        'type' => 'article',
        'uid' => 1,
        'status' => 1,
        'comment' => 0,
        'promote' => 0,
        'language'  => 'hi'
    );
    $entity = entity_create ('node', $values);
    $ewrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
    $ewrapper->title->set($title);      
    $ewrapper->field_body->set(array('value' => $body,'format'=>'full_html'));
    $ewrapper->save();
}
```

The nodes are display very well in the node view page, like this

[image]

But Ckeditor  doesn't perform the text formats (line breaks and ...). Like this

[image]

What is the problem?

---

## More information

This is the result of Firebug when inspecting the Body value of the CKEditor

[image]

Comment: did you try to see source of this data? ( I mean source of ckeditor ), is there html tags like <br> exists ?

Comment: @zhilevan There is no `<br/>` tag in CKEditor

Comment: No, just push *source button* of ckeditor on top left,

Comment: @zhilevan I tried that. All the text is in a single `<p>`, As the Firebug shows

Comment: do you see any <br> in  inspecting body rendered field in node view ?

Comment: @zhilevan Yes, There was <br> in node view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my experience `<br>` causes this problem ,my solution for this is to replace all `<br>` with `<br />`  before saving in `body field`

**So** try

```
$body =   str_replace("<br\s*>", "<br />",nl2br($item->body_value));
```

Comment: According to the link, is it related to the value of "Filtered HTML" text format?

Comment: @JimmyKo I changed it ;) this solution will work, I had the same situation before.

Comment: @zhilevan Thank you very much. I will try it and let you know the result

Comment: @Drupalist you're welcome,I hope work for you

Comment: @JimmyKo do you see according to my experience worked? :)

Comment: @zhilevan no doubt that your method should work. I just noticed the point mentioned in the link and want to know if it is better solution.. LOL

Comment: @JimmyKo thanks dude, we are here to help each other, thanks for your notice to improve my answer ;)